# How to add an external library via Webpack Encore in a Symfony-Application?

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

In a Symfony Application, we use Webpack & Encore for management of our custom javascript libraries.

However, we also want to add some external libraries like web3.js.

How to do that?

Our webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .addEntry('apiPlatform', './assets/apiPlatformCustomize.js')
  .addEntry('shop-entry', './assets/shop/entry.js')
  .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
  .enableSassLoader()
  .autoProvidejQuery()
;
```

For injecting `jQuery` it is quiet easy thanks to a convinient method. But how to do other external libraries that one would install with `npm install web3`?

I have seen something like `addExternals` but could not find anything about it how to use it properly.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You do not add external vendor libs directly in the webpack.config.js file. Rather you add import them into the main app.js or secondary page entry files and then use them in those scripts. I recommend you watch https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would say :
Do not import it inside webpack config.

Add entry is your "js" entry file for your application.
It mean if you install external libraries you want to access using

```
npm install alibrary
```

You will import it inside you "main.js" file.

**Here is a example :**

Inside webpack.config.js

```
.addEntry('website', './assets/website.js')
.splitEntryChunks() // this line is important to avoid multiple entry for css and js but require a website.css to work properly
```

Then inside you main twig file :

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('website') }} // inside <header> tag for css

{% block javascripts %} // at the bottom of your <body>
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('website') }} for.js
{% endblock %}
```

Now your website.js is correctly imported inside your app.
Now, if you want jquery install it :

```
npm i jquery
```

Then inside your website.js

```
import 'jquery-form/dist/jquery.form.min'
import $ from "jquery";
```

Now jquery is available inside website.js and your app.

Depending on which library you want sometimes only a basic import is required.

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

Is specific to jquery in order to make it work